# How can Get a bit Text Field Data of Database in java

Tags: java, sql, database, string, jdbc

i am using following code for get data from database but data is in big quantity so string is not hold all data so what is the process to get all data from database

```
     spst=scon.prepareStatement("SELECT dbQuery FROM alyss where license=?");
     spst.setString(1, key);
     ResultSet rs = spst.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){
     DBQuery = rs.getNString("dbQuery");
     }
```

Comment: yes i have more than 2 billion character.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`Reader reader=rs.getNCharacterStream(columnIndex) ;`

It is intended for use when accessing **NCHAR,NVARCHAR and LONGNVARCHAR** columns

Code

```
   java.sql.Statement st=connection.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT ApplicationId FROM application");

    while(rs.next())
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
        Reader reader=null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream =   new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
            reader=rs.getNCharacterStream(1 /*you can use here column name also*/);
            int c;
            while( (c=reader.read())!=-1)
            {
                fileOutputStream.write(c) ;
            }

        }           
        catch(Exception e){}
        finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can save these data in a file

Comment: Vishvesh this code is not working properly this code give java.lang.NullPointerException Execption